# Count Published & Draft Posts Associated With Each Term

Tags: taxonomy, terms, count

I am already doing a get_terms query to get all of the terms that are for a related taxonomy.

```
if(!empty($slug)) {
    $terms_args = array(
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'fields'     => 'all',
        'pad_counts' => true,
    );
    $terms = get_terms($slug, $terms_args);
    return $terms;
}
```

These terms are to then go into a dropdownlist.

```
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if($term->count > 0){
            $output .= '<option value="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . ' (' . $term->count . ') </option>';
        }
    }
}
```

However, my problem with this is that I also need to add together the number of draft posts to the number of published posts for each term. Currently I can get all of the terms but the count only counts the number of published posts associated with a particular term. Is there a way that I can get the count to also count the number of draft posts associated with the term as well as the number of published posts?